# Load xml file with bad format

Tags: mysql, xml

I intend to load xml file into my database with LOAD XML INFILE function. It works, but I'm facing an issue with this type of xml :

```
<response>
   <point id="DP_032113" name="data1" value="18.0"/>
   <point id="DP_042113" name="data2" value="190"/>
   <point id="DP_032753" name="data1" value="14.0"/>
</response>
```

If I add :

```
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<point>'
```

I have the result : subquery returns more than one row.

And if I don't add this line, I have this result : 0 rows affected.

I understand that the line "ROWS IDENTIFIED BY" won't work well in this case, but I can't change the xml format answer because it came from a web server :/.

Do you have any idea how to load this xml file on my database ?

Comment: Can you post the table structure and the expected result?

Comment: There are three columns : id as primiary key (varchar), name as text and value as float. I need to refresh the value of the data points.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

File: `'/path/to/file/point.xml'`:

```xml
<response>
   <point id="DP_032113" name="data1" value="18.0"/>
   <point id="DP_042113" name="data2" value="190"/>
   <point id="DP_032753" name="data1" value="14.0"/>
</response>
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `point`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `point` (
    ->   `id`  VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `name` TEXT,
    ->   `value` DECIMAL(7, 2)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/point.xml'
    ->   INTO TABLE `point`
    ->   ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<point>';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `value`
    -> FROM
    ->   `point`;
+-----------+-------+--------+
| id        | name  | value  |
+-----------+-------+--------+
| DP_032113 | data1 |  18.00 |
| DP_032753 | data1 |  14.00 |
| DP_042113 | data2 | 190.00 |
+-----------+-------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Well it works, I don't know what has changed. Still, Thanks.